# How can I get the current cache of a target DNS server?

Tags: mac, dns, nameserver

I know I can do something like: `sudo killall -INFO mDNSResponder`, and then just check the `/var/log/system.log`, but I want to be able to get the cache dump from a target DNS server.

Is this possible?
I'm on a mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no standard protocol for dumping the cache of an arbitrary DNS server. If it's a server you own/run, see the documentation for your DNS server software to see how to dump the cache in whatever software you're running.

Comment: I'm more-so interested in mapping networks I don't necessarily own. I wonder if there's a probing technique that can be used here to discover information?

Comment: Oh, it sounds like maybe what you want is not necessarily to just dump the cache on a recursive/resolving DNS server, but to get a zone transfer from an authoritative DNS server for a given zone (domain). A recursive/resolving DNS server's *cache* usually just contains random crap that clients of that server did lookups on. It doesn't necessarily tell you anything about the names of hosts in a given domain. Getting a zone transfer from an authoritative name server could get you a list of all the hostnames in that domain.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was starting to lean towards; glad you mentioned it. I'm assuming zone transfers are pretty locked down though? I wouldn't imagine most nameservers handing out their zone resolution information to just any schmuck.

Comment: @ctote: The recent trend is to limit it, though some people (including myself) still don't see any reason to – DNS used to be entirely public.